# I want a code to fill in the form automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

Instead of filling out the form each time, I want a code to fill in the form automatically so I do not have to do it again and again.

Link: https://www.locker-ambin.co.il/creditcard/choosinglocker/

like this:

1: נס ציונה
2: שש שנתי אליעזר בן יהודה

[image]

Comment: Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can give those input fields id values and then use

```
document.getElementById("mytext").value = "My value";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify a `value` attribute for text fields:

`<input value="hello"  type="text" class="input ui-autocomplete-input" id="choose_location" autocomplete="off">`

Answer (score 0):

See code below:

```js
document.getElementById("choose_city").value = "נס ציונה";
document.getElementById("choose_location").value ="אליעזר בן יהודה";
```

```html
<div class="student_num">
            <div class="student_num_r">
                בחר ישוב:
                <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span><input type="text" class="input ui-autocomplete-input" id="choose_city" value="" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="student_num_l">
                בחר בית ספר:
                <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span><input type="text" class="input ui-autocomplete-input" id="choose_location" value="" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: you can add link to html with your js file or apply `<script>...</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a bookmarklet? Create a bookmark and save this code into it. Then you can click it when you are on the page

```js
javascript:(function() {
document.getElementById("choose_city").value = "נס ציונה";
document.getElementById("choose_location").value ="אליעזר בן יהודה";
)()
```

Comment: You don't. You go to the site and click the bookmark